# Kurtosis on groupby of pandas dataframe doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

When I apply the kurtosis function on a pandas datafame I always get following error:

> AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'kurt' of
>   'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

The following sample code works with all other statistical functions (mean(), skew(), ...), but not with kurtosis.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1,0,0,1],[0,1,2,4,5]]).T
df.columns = ['a','b']
df.groupby('a').kurt()
```

Any idea how I can apply kurtosis after groupby ?
Thanks !

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#groupby), `kurt` is not a method of the `DataFrameGroupBy` class, while `mean` and `skew` are.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the [API reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#groupby), `kurt` is not a method of the `DataFrameGroupBy` class, while `mean` and `skew` are.

This should work:

```
df.groupby('a').apply(pd.DataFrame.kurt)
```

Comment: For a similar issue, I found I needed `pd.Series.kurt` not `pd.DataFrame.kurt`

Comment: Note there's an [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40139) for allowing kurtosis on GroupBy.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid multiindex

```
df = df.groupby('a').apply(pd.DataFrame.kurt)
df['a'] = df['a'].index
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this may answer the question it would be good to explain your code in a little more detail so we all know what you did and why you did it.